# 'No action' in live copy rollout CQ5

Tags: aem, rollout

I am new to CQ5 and learning it. When I try to rollout a live copy from a blueprint page; the actions are create,update,full update, partial update and 'No action' . I would want to know when does a user get 'No action' option.

I rolled out a live copy from a blueprint page and then deleted the blueprint page and then deleted the live copy page as well. After that; if I create the blueprint page with the same name again and try to roll it out; I am getting a 'No action' and not create.

Even if I delete the live copy page and then try to to roll it out again; it does not show the action as 'create'. It display 'No action'

Is this a bug in AEM 5.6.1?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue and can't find anything. I've dug through my workflow error logs and haven't seen anything that looks helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to go to MSM rollout control center. Restore the page and detach it. So you can delete the relationship before you can re-rollout or recreate again